# Lua body_data() returns nil although request body is not empty

Tags: nginx, github, lua, webhooks

I am trying to get a payload from Github Webhook with lua code.

I am able to get and see all the headers in the request but when I ask for body_data(), the content is empty, although it is not.

Maybe I should call something else than body_data() to get the payload but I couldn't find anything else online.

This is my Lua code:

```
local method = ngx.var.request_method
local headers = ngx.req.get_headers()

if method == "POST" then
   ngx.req.read_body()
   local body_data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
   ngx.print(body_data)

   local sha = headers['X-Hub-Signature-256']
end
```

It prints out '**nil**'. The webhook payload is about 100 lines file. So why is it happening?

If I print the 'sha' variable, I do see the result. I don't see any result only for the body..

Please consult, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_body_data (starting from “This function returns nil if”)?

Comment: @un.def It has been read that's for sure, because I can get specific info from the body. The request body has zero size - how can I check this?

Comment: You've skipped the second list point: “2. the request body has been read into disk temporary files”. Try to call `ngx.req.get_body_file` (search for “body may get buffered in a temp file” for the example).

Comment: @un.def Thanks, worked. Can you please take a look here as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424475/lua-script-proxy-pass-doesnt-work-as-expected

Comment: @un.def you advise is much needed. Thank you.