# Lua script proxy_pass doesn't work as expected

Tags: nginx, lua, proxy, reverse-proxy, openresty

I am trying to make a reverse proxy with Lua script, Nginx is my proxy.

This is my .lua script part that makes the proxy_pass:

```
if content == "200" then
   proxy_pass https://5dea42df1eeb.ngrok.io;
   ngx.print("OK!")
else
   return ngx.exit (ngx.HTTP_NOT_ALLOWED)
end
```

I always get **500 internal server error**. And this is ONLY happens when I put this line into my script:

```
proxy_pass https://5dea42df1eeb.ngrok.io;
```

Please let me know what could be wrong with my implementation

Comment: `proxy_pass` is not a Lua statement.  It is a NIGNX directive.  It was designed for using in a NGINX config file outside of Lua script

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Is there a way to config my lua script to have proxy_pass? I want to make proxy_pass if and only if content == 200. And not through nginx.config.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff your advise is much needed here please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have experience with NGINX.  Add "open-resty" tag to call for skilled users.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff So there's no way to make reverse proxy from lua at all?

Comment: You can use [ngx.balancer](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/balancer.md) to dynamically dispatch requests to upstreams. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53168425/how-to-dispatch-tcp-request-to-backends-with-first-byte-of-content-in-openresty/55250233#55250233)

Comment: @un.def Can you please take a look on this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66527896/lua-script-does-not-close-nginx-although-ngx-close-defined

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Can you also take a look on this thread? Critical for me.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66527896/lua-script-does-not-close-nginx-although-ngx-close-defined